# VSTS Hosted VS2017 Agent License Expired

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build definition that calls devenv.com through a command line task. The build definition uses provided "Hosted VS2017" agent queue. This build was working fine up until May 5th. Now my build has started failing with the following error message. Has anyone else seen this before and know how to resolve?

```
2018-05-07T15:29:34.2870437Z Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.27428.2027.
2018-05-07T15:29:34.2870634Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
2018-05-07T15:29:34.2870871Z 
2018-05-07T15:29:34.2870992Z The license for Visual Studio has expired.
2018-05-07T15:29:34.2871309Z 
2018-05-07T15:29:40.1187011Z The evaluation period for this product has ended.
2018-05-07T15:29:40.6652780Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I'm currently working with VSTS support and it sounds like this may be an issue on their end. Will hopefully know soon.

Comment: Can you share the detail logs by adding a variable `system.debug` with the value `true`? And can you share the detail script for the command line task for how the  devenv.com is called?

Comment: And also please make sure the build is queued by Hosted VS2017 agent. Based on the log, the VS version is `15.0.27428.2027`, but Hosted VS2017 agent actually use the version `15.6.5+27428.2027` (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md#visual-studio-2017-enterprise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with the VSTS support team, they confirmed this is an issue with the Hosted VS2017 agent pool. They are working on updating the agent pool with the latest image which is expected to take 3-4 days. The issue should be resolved on Sunday May 13, 2018.